# Select from multiple PL/SQL collections of the same type

Tags: sql, oracle, collections, oracle11gr2

there are types

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DATE_RANGE IS OBJECT (
    STARTDATE DATE,
    ENDDATE DATE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DATE_RANGES_T IS TABLE OF DATE_RANGE;
```

and table with collection per row

```
---------------------------------------------------------
    | COLUMN
---------------------------------------------------------
ROW | DATE_RANGES_T(
    |     DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-01',DATE '2021-01-02'),
    |     DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-03',DATE '2021-01-04'),
    |     DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-05',DATE '2021-01-06')
    | )
---------------------------------------------------------
ROW | DATE_RANGES_T(
    |     DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-07',DATE '2021-01-08'),
    |     DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-09',DATE '2021-01-10')
    | )
---------------------------------------------------------
ROW | DATE_RANGES_T(
    |     DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-11',DATE '2021-01-12')
    | )
---------------------------------------------------------
```

is it possible to select all date_range's objects from this table to resultset like that?

```
DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-01',DATE '2021-01-02')
DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-03',DATE '2021-01-04')
DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-05',DATE '2021-01-06')
DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-07',DATE '2021-01-08')
DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-09',DATE '2021-01-10')
DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-11',DATE '2021-01-12')
```

something like this

```
WITH TT AS (
    SELECT DATE_RANGES_T(
        DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-01',DATE '2021-01-02'),
        DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-03',DATE '2021-01-04'),
        DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-05',DATE '2021-01-06')
    ) DT FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_RANGES_T(
        DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-07',DATE '2021-01-08'),
        DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-09',DATE '2021-01-10')
    )  FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_RANGES_T(
        DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-11',DATE '2021-01-12')
    ) FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    (SELECT STARTDATE FROM TABLE(DT)), (SELECT ENDDATE FROM TABLE(DT))
FROM TT;
```

but just with no `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row` error occurs

in Oracle database 11.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the TABLE() function as follows:

```
WITH TT AS (
    SELECT DATE_RANGES_T(
        DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-01',DATE '2021-01-02'),
        DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-03',DATE '2021-01-04'),
        DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-05',DATE '2021-01-06')
    ) DT FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_RANGES_T(
        DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-07',DATE '2021-01-08'),
        DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-09',DATE '2021-01-10')
    )  FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_RANGES_T(
        DATE_RANGE(DATE '2021-01-11',DATE '2021-01-12')
    ) FROM DUAL
)
SELECT T.STARTDATE, T.ENDDATE FROM TT, TABLE(TT.DT) T;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fbc868ecf3546fbd2df1c31edfcee9c0)